# Javascript global declaration

Tags: javascript

I've just started out with javascript and came across this line in a file called global.js There is only one line in the file. I'm not sure what does App do. Any ideas?

*Filename: globals.js*

```
//The Application 
App = {};
```

Comment: You have a file with one line of code somewhere and you're expecting us to know what it does ?

Comment: It creates an empty object. Thats it.

Comment: @adeneo - yes. I'm not looking for a long blown out answer. I'm just not sure on its usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it creates an object with a name of App... that's all it does.

Answer (score 1):

I would assume that the idea behind the global.js file in your case is to include the file in your base html/template so that the variables in there can be accessed from anywhere in the app.

In some of our projects, we've had global files like this containing references to collections and "setting" variables, which is quite handy :)

Comment: Thanks @jesuli! I'll have to look into the other pages.

Answer (score 0):

It is creating an object named App in the global namespace. App has no functions or attributes (yet).

Answer (score 0):

It (implicitly) declares a variable called `App` in a "global" context and assigns an empty object as its value. Assuming this is used on a web page somewhere, it's the same as declaring `window.App = {}`.

How this affects the rest of your application, we won't know until you post more relevant code.

Comment: Thanks pete for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

This script just instantiate this empty Object. Probably, others scripts that ran along with this uses that object and depends that it is created there.